# When reviewing edits which are big formatting cleanups, should I check carefully or assume they've done it right?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, code-formatting

I've just received permission to approve/reject edits, and I'm getting quite a few where people are basically fixing up badly formatted code. Sometimes these contain around 20+ lines.

I could carefully go through each line and check that it's correct, or I could assume that they've done it correctly after a few quick sample checks. I want to only approve edits with confidence, but at the same time, if I have to carefully go through every single line, then we may as well just do code format cleanups ourselves.

What's the best approach in these situations?

Comment: that depends on what has been changed. If  new `tags` have been added or the question has been modified, I look very carefully. For formatting issues (I hope I don't end up on the wrong side of moderators for saying this.. :P) I check whether the code is *readable* in one go, an additional space here and there is fine as long as the code is *readable*.

Comment: There are two views : "rendered output" and "markdown". Make sure you utilize both the views. You should check carefully.

Comment: Carefully but quickly enough that you're faster than the 3 other people who aren't checking carefully......

Comment: You can normally tell relatively easily from the diff coloring if it's just formatting changes, or if actual code has changed. I think you should check. It's not very common, but I have certainly seen it that the code was broken during formatting changes. Mostly unintentionally, but that's what reviews are supposed to catch.

Comment: Never assume they done it right - you *are* reviewer. Often they sell "I like that kind of braces / indent / ..." as "better formatting" - I would reject such edits unless they are really improve readability - like, I can read code now without horizontal scroll etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My advice, *take as long as you need to review an edit*.

Yes, it may be time consuming, *at first*. But, as you continue to read/validate edits, you'll learn how to review quicker. Besides practising, learning (more of) the English language and refreshing your knowledge of our formatting rules will also certainly help.

The only way to review with confidence is to review *thoroughly*. If it takes you 3 times to read an edit (in its entirety), good. It's all part of gaining experience. Even if you take long enough for the edit to be approved/rejected, you can always go back to the post and rollback/edit it.

<sup>Remember, if you're not sure what to do with an edit, **skip it** and ask us (Meta) for help.</sup>

Comment: Downside: Robo-reviewers are fast. =(

Comment: @jpmc26: It's not a contest.  (Though roboreviews upstaging your honest review can be quite frustrating.)

Comment: @tmyklebu It kinda is. If the edit is approved/rejected before you finish reviewing, then you've wasted your time. I agree whole-heartedly with the sentiment here, but it's not effective if people are blindly approving/rejecting everything and beat you to it.

Comment: @tmyklebu I'm not sure that I'd call it a *contest*, but it absolutely is a *race*. The last 3 or 4 times I've entered a custom reject reason (+30sec penalty) I've come in 4th at which point you can't even submit your review.

Comment: To add to last note,please search whether the same scenario has already been discussed, before posting for help.

Comment: @jpmc26: I think we should challenge this *waste*, rather than blame the robo-reviewers. I would think that *as long as you complete the review*, your opinion should be taken into account. Reviews are not supposed to be a race, so we should not make them be one. Of course, a proper timeout feature might be necessary to avoid waiting for ages...

Comment: +1 for "if you're not sure what to do with an edit, skip it."

Comment: @jpmc26 Even if they 'beat you to it', you should still edit/rollback afterwards if you are confident enough that it is the right course of action.

Comment: @OGHaza: If you lose the race, the only effect is that some improvement to the site doesn't happen.  No skin off your back.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm in agreement. The causes and effects of robo-reviewers and possible solutions are well discussed elsewhere; I just wanted to point out their relevance to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Take your time and make *really* sure. Then go back to the edit. If people disagreed with you, they probably are a robo-(or at least low-quality) reviewer (use an "other" flag to tell a mod with examples that you can find under the "activity" tab of their profile). If it was approved, you can roll it back. If it needs experience in the language or the like that you don't have, skip it.